# Jquery load not loading module into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I'm using jquery ONCLICK to load a module into a div.   The code is below.

<

```
function shomdes(whrfrm,fboxx) { // Show the description for a select measure.
         // Called from the following modules wih the enumerated whrfrm value: 
         // emm explorm explormx explorm2 explorm2x explorm3 explorm4  explorm4x cmf2me graph1
         //  3     0       0        2        2         3        4         4        0      0

         var vflg = 0;
         var mea = '';   
      
         for( var i=0; i<fboxx.options.length; i++ ) { // Find the selected measure.
           if ( fboxx.options[i].selected && fboxx.options[i].value != '' ) { // Selected and non-blank.
             mea = fboxx.options[i].value; // Get the measure selected to display the description for.
             break;          
           } 
         }

         if ( mea != '' ) {                                 
           \$('#graphhere').load('imdesc.cgi?str='+document.Choice.govlevel.value+'~x'+':'+mea+':'+'7x~'+document.Choice.echoice[document.Choice.echoice.selectedIndex].value+':1');               
         } else {
             vflg = lrtMsg('No measure has been selected.','mea'); // A measure must be selected.                                          
           }
  
       }
```

> 

I call shomdes from a button on the UI.  I've looked at some of the earlier posts and tried some of the suggestions with no luck.   I've verified that all parameters are right, and it does enter the 'if ( mea != '' ) {' branch, but does not execute.  I'm using this approach elsewhere and it works.  There is nothing in the console.

I've tried to load a measure description into a div using load() as above and using innerHTML.  I felt like the jquery was not loading in the load() case, so I've tried using different jquery libraries with no change.  On the innerHTML case, I didn't seem to be able to get the quotes right in the OBJ data part.  I expect it to show the description in the div in both cases.  But nothing happens.  The imdesc module is not loading.   Any help will be appreciated.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with different arguments in the load. The first below works. The second does not. If I add the statex variable or use
`document.Choice.echoice[document.Choice.echoice.selectedIndex].value` directly, the load quits working. Without that, it works. The value is correct. I'm not seeing it.

Works:

```js
$('#graphhere').load('imdesc.cgi?str='+document.Choice.govlevel.value+ '~x'+':'+mea+':'+'7:1');
```

Does not work:

```js
var statex = document.Choice.echoice[document.Choice.echoice.selectedIndex].value;
                   
$('#graphhere').load('imdesc.cgi?str='+document.Choice.govlevel.value+ '~x:'+mea+':7x~'+statex+':1');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the load would not take the document.Choice.echoice[document.Choice.echoice.selectedIndex].value.  It did resolve correctly.   So I recoded to pass the echoice array in like I had done with the measures array.   And the load process worked that way.
I would like to understand why I could not work with thedocument.Choice.echoice[document.Choice.echoice.selectedIndex].value, but this problem can be closed.   Thanks for your response DevGuy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).